# Game search engine in a p2p format

Tags: java, multiplayer, peer-to-peer

I am currently using Java to develop a multiplayer game engine. However, I am stuck on one thing. Many games (Overwatch, DotA) have automatic game search engines - you click a button and the computer automatically finds you a game. My first thought to replicate this was to have a server that every computer running the game would connect to, then would find groups of, say, in a 3v3 team game, 6, start a new room with those 6, and run the game. However, there is one major problem here: I am only 14 and am nowhere NEAR being able to afford a server farm that would be necessary. Since I cannot afford this, a single server running the game would be out of the question, so I've been looking into the p2p (peer-to-peer) format. The problem is, I cannot think of a way to have an automatic game search engine in a p2p format without a host server. Is there any way that I can replicate this with a p2p format?

Comment: You're 14. Don't worry about making multiplayer games at this stage in your career. If you *really* want to, though, stick with direct-connect via IP address or via something like Android's Game Center (there are plugins that manage all the networking aspects for you for some game engines). Multiplayer games are so much more complex than single player games, so many things can go wrong on a technical level.

Comment: Getting own  general purpose virtual machine costs as low as 10 usd a month, have you considered setting up one of such services, or is your budget even lower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no way to do this 100% peer to peer, as cozmic pointed out. You need some kind of third party that establishes the connection between the clients.
Bittorrent uses tracker servers for this for example.

There are however a couple of free solutions that you could use, in order for your clients to discover other clients.

First of all, there is [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) on which you can host small programs (like your own java connection server). I don't think it would be enough to host the entire game server on it, but as long as it just establishes the connection between the clients, and one of your clients is the host (p2p) it should work fine. Heroku provides 550 hours per month for free, which amounts to about 18 hours per day, so your game wouldn't work 24/7. Fortunately you can increase this to be basically 100% of the time, by adding a credit card. It **won't** charge you anything, it just needs this so it can verify that you don't abuse the service.

The second option would be to use something like [Firebase-Database](http://firebase.google.com), and have the clients enter their connection details (IP address) into the database.

Finally, you can check your router settings, if you can open ports, you can host this server on your computer. You would just have to use some dyndns service, that resolves a domain, to your IP address since most residential providers change your IP address every now and then.

To actually establish the connection, you might want to use a protocol like [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) and if that fails [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT). There are a lot of free stun servers out there, like [these](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933).

Comment: -1 because of borrowing credit card. Don't let people use your credit card and don't use other people's credit card in case you mess up and something happens.

Comment: Fair enough. Updated the answer so it doesn't suggest this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Peer to peer matchmaking is always done via a third party server:

When a game is created, a message is sent to the matchmaking server informing it that a game with < max players is available.

when a player is added to the game, the matchmaking server is updated. if the max players is reached, another notification is sent, which removes the game from the list of available games.

If a player drops out, the server is again notified, allowing the game to be re-advertised.

When the game is destroyed (finished or cancelled), the server will again remove it from the list of available games.

Clients can, in turn, connect to the matchmaking server to find IP addresses of available games, when the player selects a game, the server sends that IP address on a first come, first served basis, and the client then connects directly, and the game begins.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't yet programmed anything network-related myself, but when reading this question I had the following idea:

First off, I can't think of any way to achieve this without any kind of server. Think about it, how should one client of your game know about any other client in the world if there is no server connecting them or if the user doesn't give it any address to connect to. I can't imagine that there would be a way this could work.

The idea that I head however consists of a small server, that is responsible for connecting clients only and then let the clients establish a connection between each other themselves. This way as much work as possible is done by the client and all the server effectively does, is to send a client an address to connect to.

The server would be really inexpensive then.

One thing to consider with this is, that you would need to take great care about the protection of user data when sending it to clients to connect to.